# Git won't commit staged changes

Tags: git

I have a file staged for commit. Whether I do `git commit` or `git commit -m "message"`, nothing happens. My shell goes down two lines, but nothing is printed. If I do `git status` afterwards, it still shows that file staged for commit.

I've tried googling this, trying to find other cases where git commit appears to have no effect, but to no avail. I've been using git for a few years, but I have never seen this happen. Has anyone seen this before?

Output:

```
➜  my-project git:(fix_racket_example) ✗ git status
# On branch fix_racket_example
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/js/core/controllers/homeController.js
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  my-project git:(fix_racket_example) ✗ git add .
➜  my-project git:(fix_racket_example) ✗ git status
# On branch fix_racket_example
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   app/js/core/controllers/homeController.js
#
➜  my-project git:(fix_racket_example) ✗ git commit -m "Fixed racket example"


➜  my-project git:(fix_racket_example) ✗ git commit


➜  my-project git:(fix_racket_example) ✗ git status
# On branch fix_racket_example
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   app/js/core/controllers/homeController.js
#
➜  my-project git:(fix_racket_example) ✗ 
➜  my-project git:(fix_racket_example) ✗
```

Comment: by any chance, are you running on windows?

Comment: Nope, Ubuntu 13.10, git version 1.8.3.2

Comment: i'm not a git wiz, but what i'd do is grab the head revision from git and do a binary compare on the two files.

Comment: What happens if you `reset` and then `add` and `commit` again?

Comment: Show us some output?  Ideally of `git status`, and also show the exact `add` and `commit` commands that you're using.

Comment: I added the output, copied from my terminal. I've tried resetting and re-committing, I've tried deleting the branch and re-creating it, I even tried restarting my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well like `5 minutes ago`, I just `restarted` my PC and then it was doing as it should.

Maybe its `helpful` for other people when they are reading this.

Comment: I'd like to think that 'try turning it off and on again' is something people on this site don't need to be told...

Comment: I'd tried everything except for this, which fixed the issue. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pre-commit git hook specified (in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`), and it fails, then your commit can fail silently. This results in nothing seeming to happen when you run any variant of `git commit`, as the command failed before it even got to the commit portion!

Removing the pre-commit hook, or fixing the underlying issue within it, should resolve the issue.

Comment: this was my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the repository and then cloning again seems to have fixed the problem. Something in the .git directory must have gotten corrupted. Thanks!